# Testing latest code on Git remote master branch before merging

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have a few commits already but someone pushed some changes on the master branch and I would like to play it safe by checking out and test the changes before merging it into my local master branch. How do I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can fetch the remote branch which you can reference using FETCH_HEAD and then checkout that branch.

> git fetch remote_branch
>
> git checkout FETCH_HEAD

this will put you in detached state but if you just want to temporarily test these changes this is fine.

and after you are done testing you can merge back it to your branch.

> git checkout your_prevous_branch
>
> git merge FETCH_HEAD

Comment: There should be a one page guide covering all git basics and basic scenarios because reading docs for Git is annoying and time consuming. That page will attract lots of traffic. My gift to you as a thanks.